# Connect to Webdav (https) with domain\user

Tags: osx, macintosh, https, webdav

I have a problem trying to connect with our network webdav share on mac osx. I can connect from windows, so it's working. On Mac OSX I have set the routes, and I can connect when using "Transmit" but not with "Mac Finder" or any other webdav client for mac so it's not a network or login problem, but a problem with the applications. I tried Mac Finder, Cyberduck, AnyClient and lot's of webdav clients from sourceforge. I could buy Transmit, but we have a lot of users and 34$ per license is a lot of money, if you only want to connect to webdav with it.

Situation facts:

- Two company networks, each with it's own MS ActiveDirectory infrastructure
- Webdav is in network A, I have an Account for network A
- My Macbook is in network B, and the routes are set. (as said, works with Transmit)
- I don't have administrative access to the webdav server, so changing settings is not an option

Since I'm in a different network as the webdav server I need to specify the domain on logon, so login on transmit looks like this:

```
Protocol: https
Port: 443
Server: 192.168.0.3
Path: webdav_transfer
user: domainA\username (otherwise, the macbook would set domainB as default)
```

As said, this works on Transmit, but not on any of the other clients. I think it's a problem with the domainA\username part. Somehow transmit can use it, while the others can't. It's also working in Safari, but I can't upload from there.

I already tried the following in mac finder:

```
https://domainA\username@192.168.0.3/webdav_transfer
https://username@192.168.0.3/webdav_transfer
https://domainA\\username@192.168.0.3/webdav_transfer
https://domainA\\\\username@192.168.0.3/webdav_transfer
https://domainA:username:password@192.168.0.3/webdav_transfer
```

I found out that some apps change the URL to

```
https://domainA%5Cusername@192.168.0.3/webdav_transfer
```

So the \ changes to %5C
It's probably just a format error, but I don't know how I can get the domainA part properly into my https request.

EDIT: New information:

I tried mounting the webdav share with mount_webdav, which didn't work either - no error message, but the share isn't mounted either. I think (have no proove), that the problem with mount_webdav (and therefore Mac Finder) that it lacks proper ssl support.  Through port I installed cadaver, a Unix webdav command line client (sudo port install cadaver). With cadaver I'm able to connect to the webdav share and download/upload stuff. Unfortunately, even though everything works for me now, this is no possible solutions for our maclings (they want a GUI).

I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Finder -> Connect to Server...  <kbd>⌘K</kbd>

Enter `https://192.168.0.3/webdav_transfer` as "Server address"

Respond to the Username/Password challenge as "domainA\username" for username.

If that doesn't work, see http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/WebDAV for possible reasons; you may be out of luck without admin access to the WebDAV server.

Comment: Thanks, for the link. Brought me one step closer to a solution.